# Calling multiple functions from within jQuery .on("change"... event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I want to call two functions when *myValue* changes, and while this works just fine:

```
this.myValue.on("change", $.proxy(self.functionOne, self));
this.myValue.on("change", $.proxy(self.functionTwo, self));
```

neither function is called in this case:

```
this.myValue.on("change", function () {
    $.proxy(self.functionOne, self);
    $.proxy(self.functionTwo, self);
})
```

It isn't a huge deal to me if I can't call both functions within one change event like this right now, but I'm pretty new to jQuery and would like to learn why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call the functions defined in the `$.proxy()`:

```
this.myValue.on("change", function () {
    $.proxy(self.functionOne, self)();
    $.proxy(self.functionTwo, self)();
})
```

Note the trailing `()`.

Comment: Wow, that took me a while to spot :)

Comment: Mmh, why not just `self.functionOne()`? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use the native `apply` or `call` instead

```
this.myValue.on("change", function() {
    self.functionOne.apply(this, arguments);
    self.functionTwo.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

`$.proxy` takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context, and that works when the returned function is referenced, but not the way you're doing it in the callback as the returned function is never called.

You could of course use `$.proxy` and just call the returned function as well

```
this.myValue.on("change", function () {
    $.proxy(self.functionOne, self)();
    $.proxy(self.functionTwo, self)();
});
```

or just let jQuery handle it, it optimizes events and uses an internal queue anyway

```
this.myValue.on("change", self.functionOne);
this.myValue.on("change", self.functionTwo);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$.proxy` method will just return a function, but not call it. You can use:

```
self.functionOne.call(self);
self.functionTwo.call(self);
```

The call function calls the function, and you get to pass in the 'context' ie. what gets used as 'this' within the function, much like in $.proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you call it simple like this?

```
this.myValue.on("change", function () {
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
})
```

Comment: i guess `this != self`

Comment: What makes you think he functions are available in the current scope?

Comment: good point @FelixKling but,, isn't he proxying to self,, or current scope?